# How to create shared header file for kernel filesystem and user program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, header-files

At what path should I include a header file that is needed to be accessed by both a linux kernel custom filesystem and a user program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existed filesystem drivers place their headers, which are also intended for user space, under `include/uapi/linux/`. Here you may find `jffs2.h`, `btrfs.h` and many other filesystems-related headers.

These headers are intended to be included with

```
#include <linux/xxx.h>
```

This automatically works for the kernel.

For user this would work too, after you install "uapi" headers with `make headers_install`, rebuild C library (`libc`) against new headers, and rebuild gcc against new C library. Otherwise, you need to copy required headers and adjust include directories manually.